# Refresh my PC - Overwriting data?

Tags: windows, system-recovery

Windows 10 is installed on my F:.  I also have Windows 8 installed on my C:.  Each time I try to refresh my PC (Windows 10) without overwriting data it errors: "There Was A Problem Refreshing Your PC. No Changes Were Made.".

If I was to refresh my PC overwriting data, then I assume that it is just the F:\ that is overwritten.  The F:\ is an SSD containing no personal data.  All my personal data is on the D:\ (C and D are the same hard disk).  Will the D:\ be left intact?

Is it just the Windows partition (F:) that is completely overwritten? What about the C:.

Comment: Unclear what the exact setup is - drive letters are relative to the OS. You can't have Windows 10 on F:, all Windows version are always on C:. Do you mean you see the Windows 10 disk as F: if you boot Windows 8? What are the drives when you boot Windows 10?

Comment: @Aganju, Windows 10 is installed on an SSD drive.  Windows 10 is installed on a hard drive.  When I login to Windows 8, it says the Windows 10 installation is the F drive.

Comment: Only the Windows partition is touched with both the Reset and Refresh features.